# Should I use log_level :debug in production on my Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

The default for production.rb is:

`config.log_level = :info`

However, I really like to see the SQL queries and extra logging in my production environment.

Changing the log level to:

`config.log_level = :debug`

Is this a terribly bad practice? How much overhead does this add to my application to have Rails do this extra logging?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simply a question of how large a log file you're willing to deal with. I suggest setting it to `:debug` for a few days, and then decide based on the resulting log sizes. This is a decision that may change day-to-day, based also on what you need debugged, and how many and how verbose your debug statements are.

Answer (score 1):

For your reference below are some links for rails best practices that I found while Googling:

> [Best Practices for a Web App Staging Server (on a budget)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565647/best-practices-for-a-web-app-staging-server-on-a-budget)
>
> http://kpumuk.info/ruby-on-rails/flexible-application-configuration-in-ruby-on-rails/
>
> http://railsware.com/blog/2013/10/16/rails-configuration-in-the-proper-way/
>
> [Best practices for Ruby on Rails *feature* deployment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9799570/best-practices-for-ruby-on-rails-feature-deployment)

Here is rails 4 production logging and new features:

> http://rubyjunky.com/cleaning-up-rails-4-production-logging.html

Also in other way you can do it with easily by taking back up of production DB on your local machine and test / debug those data in the way that you want.